# SQL function inside function and equation in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want every User that signed on in the last 30 Days, and to check their first 7 days of activity. `Date` maps their activity, once they've signed on. `Day` is how many days have passed since the user signed on.

I want something like this.

```
SELECT UserID, Date
FROM Web
WHERE (Day < = 30) and ( CONVERT(date, Date) - CONVERT(date,CURDATE()) - Day) <= 7 )
ORDER BY UserID asc, Date desc;
```

My SQL skills are very basic, so I need it to be simple as possible.

EDITED:

I'm thinking maybe something like this:

```
SELECT UserID, DT 
FROM test
WHERE (Day < = 30) and DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD( DAY, -Day, GETDATE() ), Date) <= 7  
ORDER BY UserID asc, DT desc;
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used, some product specific SQL there...

Comment: @jarlh in this case MS SQL SERVER

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I don't see the relationship between your query and your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT UserID, Date
FROM Web
WHERE (Day < = 30) and DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, -[Day], GETDATE()), [Date]) <= 7
ORDER BY UserID asc, Date desc;
```

Comment: this gives me dates from the last 7 days, what I need is dates from 7 days after the user signed on. which is expressed by `Day` only `Day` counts how many days have passed since signed on.

Comment: maybe use `DATEADD( DAY, -Day, GETDATE() )` inside the DATEDIFF??

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I misunderstood the requirement. I still don't quite understand what the day and date values represent, could you explain further?

Comment: so `Day` represents how many days ago a user signed up for a service. so i only want people who signed up in the last month, so Day <=30

Comment: `Date` is an activity. and what I want is to follow the activity of users 7 days after they signed on, and only users who signed on within the last month.

Comment: I want a list of the activity of each user with the restrictions above.

Comment: Ah, in that case, yes a DATEADD function with a negative Day should work, I'll update the answer.

Comment: does the `day` and `date` have to be in square brackets?

Comment: Technically no, but date is a SQL keyword so to avoid confusion the brackets tell SQL it is a name rather than a keyword.